# Unable to pass 'page[size]' parameter to API request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, pagination

I'm currently attempting to get the Flippa API to return a list of 50 listings, but the default page size is only 30. Their documentation states that the 'page[size]' parameter needs to be used in order to change this attribute, but nothing I've tried works. I can't simply use 'page[size]' as a filter parameter, because of the special characters, so that's not an option. I then noticed that 'page_size' and 'page_number' are attributes listed under the meta section of the response, so I tried those as parameters - but still no luck. When I try to use 'page_size', I receive a Bad Request error. My code for this attempt is below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Flippa = require('flippa');

app.use("/public", express.static('./public/'));

app.get("/", function (request, response) {

  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post("/getdata", function(req, res) {
  flippa = new Flippa();
  flippa
  .listings
  .list
  (
    {
      filter: {status: "won", premium: true, sale_method: "auction", page_size: 50}
    }
  )
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.body);
  });

  res.end();
});


//-------------------------------------------------------------//

// listen for requests
var listener = app.listen('8888', function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

Everything works without the 'page_size' parameter (that is, no Bad Request). Here's a link to the relevant section of the Flippa documentation: https://developers.flippa.com/?javascript#pagination

If anyone could shed some light on how to implement this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean by special characters? have you tried using { "page[size]": 10 }

Comment: @IgorMoraru By special characters, I mean characters other than letters (or underscores). Yes, I've tried that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"page_size" won't work cause that is what the response meta object have. Your request needs page[size].

You can add page[size] by doing "page[size]" but maybe it expects page[size] as separate key instead of one inside filter.

```
}
  filter: {status: "won", premium: true, sale_method: "auction"},
  "page[size]": 50
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it's still giving me a Bad Request error.